# Integer showing differently when sent in discord (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My storage module is outputting 69, but when it sends a message in discord.. it says undefined.
Can someone help? (Fyi, the console.log is showing 69 as well.)

```js
const nv = await storage.get(target.id)
console.log(nv)
message.channel.send(`<@${target.id}> now has **${nv}** vouches.`)
```

Comment: That's weird, what happens if you manually set a value to `nv`, like `const nv = 5`?

Comment: @Firstdev I have tried that and it works fine. :/

Comment: So what happen when `msg.channel.send(nv)`

Comment: I found out that it was not that, but I think there is a returning problem in my module.

```js
        if (data) {
            console.log(data.vouches)
            return data.vouches;
        } else {
            console.log(0)
            return 0
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Convert The Number to a String

```js
const nv = await storage.get(target.id)
console.log(nv)
message.channel.send(`<@${target.id}> now has **${parseInt(nv)}** vouches.`)
```